# In ELF, why do the headers need to be in one segment?

Tags: linux, assembly, elf

I have made this simple ELF for learning purposes:

```
bits 64
org 0x08048000

elfHeader:
    db  0x7F, "ELF", 2, 1, 1, 0   ; e_ident
    db 0                            ; abi version
    times 7 db 0                    ; unused padding
    dw  2                         ; e_type
    dw  62                        ; e_machine
    dd  1                         ; e_version
    dq  _start                    ; e_entry
    dq  programHeader - $$        ; e_phoff
    dq  0                         ; e_shoff
    dd  0                         ; e_flags
    dw  elfHeaderSize             ; e_ehsize
    dw  programHeaderSize         ; e_phentsize
    dw  1                         ; e_phnum
    dw  0                         ; e_shentsize
    dw  0                         ; e_shnum
    dw  0                         ; e_shstrndx

elfHeaderSize  equ $ - elfHeader

programHeader:
    dd  1                         ; p_type
    dd  7                         ; p_flags
    dq  0                         ; p_offset
    dq  $$                        ; p_vaddr
    dq  $$                        ; p_paddr
    dq  fileSize                  ; p_filesz
    dq  fileSize                  ; p_memsz
    dq  0x1000                    ; p_align

programHeaderSize equ  $ - programHeader

_start:
   xor rdi, rdi
   xor eax,eax
   mov al,60
   syscall

fileSize      equ     $ - $$
```

In order to compile that code I use NASM:

```
nasm -f bin exe.asm -o exe
```

If you take a look to the `programHeader`, you will see that `p_offset` is 0, and `p_filesz` is `fileSize`. That means that the segment contains the whole file. That's something I wasn't expecting([and I'm not the only one](https://cirosantilli.com/elf-hello-world#p-191)), but apparently the Linux operating system needs the headers to be in a segment of type `PT_LOAD` so that information gets loaded.

This is the only resource I could find that mentions that fact that the headers are inside one segment: https://www.intezer.com/blog/research/executable-linkable-format-101-part1-sections-segments/

> Something important to highlight about segments is that only PT_LOAD segments get loaded into memory. Therefore, every other segment is mapped within the memory range of one of the PT_LOAD segments.
>
> In order to understand the relationship between Sections and Segments, we can picture segments as a tool to make the linux loader’s life easier, as they group sections by attributes into single segments in order to make the loading process of the executable more efficient, instead of loading each individual section into memory. The following diagram attempts to illustrate this concept:
>
> [image]

But I don't understand why Linux needs that headers to be loaded at run time. What are they used for? If they are needed for the process to run, couldn't Linux load it by himself?

EDIT:

It has been mentioned in the comments that headers don't need to be loaded, however, they are sometimes loaded anyways to avoid having to add padding. I have tried adding padding to get it 4KB aligned but it didn't work. Here's my attempt:

```
bits 64
org 0x08048000

elfHeader:
    db  0x7F, "ELF", 2, 1, 1, 0   ; e_ident
    db 0                            ; abi version
    times 7 db 0                    ; unused padding
    dw  2                         ; e_type
    dw  62                        ; e_machine
    dd  1                         ; e_version
    dq  _start                    ; e_entry
    dq  programHeader - $$        ; e_phoff
    dq  0                         ; e_shoff
    dd  0                         ; e_flags
    dw  elfHeaderSize             ; e_ehsize
    dw  programHeaderSize         ; e_phentsize
    dw  1                         ; e_phnum
    dw  0                         ; e_shentsize
    dw  0                         ; e_shnum
    dw  0                         ; e_shstrndx

elfHeaderSize  equ $ - elfHeader

programHeader:
    dd  1                         ; p_type
    dd  7                         ; p_flags
    dq  _start - $$               ; p_offset
    dq  $$                        ; p_vaddr
    dq  $$                        ; p_paddr
    dq  codeSize                  ; p_filesz
    dq  codeSize                  ; p_memsz
    dq  0x1000                    ; p_align

programHeaderSize equ  $ - programHeader

; padding until 4KB
paddingUntil4k equ 4*1024 - ($ - elfHeader)
times paddingUntil4k db 0


_start:
   xor rdi, rdi
   xor eax,eax
   mov al,60
   syscall

codeSize equ $ - _start
fileSize equ $ - $$
```

Comment: It doesn't, but the headers are usually loaded anyway as it avoids the need for padding between headers and first section in the binary.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Linux kernel needs them in memory, but the (usually glibc) dynamic loader may need them there.

Comment: @fuz Thanks, that makes sense. I have tried to add padding to get the segment 4KB-aligned but it didn't work (it crashes). Maybe I'm doing wrong. I have added the code to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But I don't understand why Linux needs that headers to be loaded at run time.

It *doesn't*.

> What are they used for? If they are needed for the process to run, couldn't Linux load it by himself?

To answer all of these questions, you need to look at the Linux kernel source.

In [the source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L820), you can see that in fact program headers do *not* need to be a part of any `PT_LOAD` segment, and that the kernel will read them all on its own.

Changing your original program like so:

```
diff -u exe.asm.orig exe.asm
--- exe.asm.orig        2021-02-07 18:54:34.449336515 -0800
+++ exe.asm     2021-02-07 18:53:19.773532451 -0800
@@ -24,9 +24,9 @@
 programHeader:
     dd  1                         ; p_type
     dd  7                         ; p_flags
-    dq  0                         ; p_offset
-    dq  $$                        ; p_vaddr
-    dq  $$                        ; p_paddr
+    dq  _start - $$               ; p_offset
+    dq  _start                    ; p_vaddr
+    dq  _start                    ; p_paddr
     dq  fileSize                  ; p_filesz
     dq  fileSize                  ; p_memsz
     dq  0x1000                    ; p_align
```

produces a program which runs fine, but in which the program header is not in the `PT_LOAD` segment:

```
 eu-readelf --all exe
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Ident Version:                     1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AMD x86-64
  Version:                           1 (current)
  Entry point address:               0x8048078
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program header entries:    56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers entries: 1
  Size of section header entries:    0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers entries: 0 ([0] not available)
  Section header string table index: 0

Section Headers:
[Nr] Name                 Type         Addr             Off      Size     ES Flags Lk Inf Al

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000078 0x0000000008048078 0x0000000008048078 0x000081 0x000081 RWE 0x1000
```

> I have tried adding padding

You didn't do that correctly. Using your "with padding" source results in the following `exe-padding`:

```
...
  Entry point address:               0x8049000
...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000008048000 0x0000000008048000 0x000009 0x000009 RWE 0x1000
```

This binary is started by the kernel, and immediately jumps to the start address `0x8049000`, which *isn't mapped* (since it's not covered by the `PT_LOAD` segment), resulting in immediate `SIGSEGV`.

To fix this, you need to adjust the entry address:

```
diff -u exe-padding.asm.orig exe-padding.asm
--- exe-padding.asm.orig        2021-02-07 18:57:31.800871195 -0800
+++ exe-padding.asm     2021-02-07 19:34:27.303071700 -0800
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@
     dw  2                         ; e_type
     dw  62                        ; e_machine
     dd  1                         ; e_version
-    dq  _start                    ; e_entry
+    dq  _start - 0x1000           ; e_entry
     dq  programHeader - $$        ; e_phoff
     dq  0                         ; e_shoff
     dd  0                         ; e_flags
```

This again produces a working executable. For the record:

```
eu-readelf --all exe-padding
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Ident Version:                     1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AMD x86-64
  Version:                           1 (current)
  Entry point address:               0x8048000
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program header entries:    56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers entries: 1
  Size of section header entries:    0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers entries: 0 ([0] not available)
  Section header string table index: 0

Section Headers:
[Nr] Name                 Type         Addr             Off      Size     ES Flags Lk Inf Al

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000008048000 0x0000000008048000 0x000009 0x000009 RWE 0x1000
```

P.S. You are linking your 64-bit program at `0x08048000`, which is the traditional load address for `i*86` (32-bit) executables. `x86_64` binaries traditionally start at `0x400000`.

**Update:**

> About the first example, p_filesz is still fileSize, I think that should get outside of the boundaries of the file.

That is correct: `p_filesz` and `p_memsz` should be reduced by the size of headers (`0x78` here). Note that both of these will be rounded up to page size (after adding `p_offset`), so for this example there is no practical difference.

**Update 2:**

> pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rgfVMrbcmJ

This results in the following `LOAD` segment:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000078 0x0000000008048000 0x0000000008048000 0x000081 0x000081 RWE 0x1000
```

This binary will not run (kernel will reject it), because it is asking the kernel to do the impossible: to `mmap` bytes at offset `0x78` to page start.

If the application performed equivalent `mmap` call, it would have gotten `EINVAL` error, because `mmap` requires that `(offset % pagesize) == (addr % pagesize)`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I think I'm starting to understand now. I tried your modifications and they seem to work. About the first example, `p_filesz` is still `fileSize`, I think that should get outside of the boundaries of the file. About the modification you made to the second example, makes a lot of sense to me, and that makes me think, shouldn't we do something similar for the first example? (instead of subtracting 0x1000 subtract the headers sizes, I tried to do so but it didn't work)

Comment: This is my failed attempt: https://pastebin.com/zD8rPy2r

Comment: Okay, I manged to get it working, but I don't understand why I couldn't have `0x400000` as the entry point :S https://quickdiff.net/?unique_id=72206A18-F92C-3821-88D1-50B14B76DC09

Comment: @tuket That seems to be a totally different question. Any reason you are not accepting this answer? It seems to me that it answered your original question _completely_.

Comment: I didn't accept yet because I still don't understand your corrections (read my first comment).

Comment: @tuket Ah, sorry I missed the first comment. I've updated the answer for your first question, but didn't understand the second one.

Comment: NP, I really apreciate your help. Let me try to explain better the second question. In the first modification you made, we aren't loading the headers anymore but the virtaddr and the entry_point are still `0x8048078`, which is `0x8048000` + header sizes. In your second example, however, those are `0x8048000`. If I take the first example, and try to set `e_entry`, `p_vaddr`, and `p_paddr` to `0x8048000` it crashes, why is that? This is the full code: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WpJTJzNkH2/

Comment: @tuket The example from http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WpJTJzNkH2 sets `e_entry == p_vaddr == p_paddr == 0x8048078` and works correctly for me. Can you point to non-working example?

Comment: Ups, sorry: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rgfVMrbcmJ/

Comment: I though it might be an alignment problem but it will crash even if I set `p_align` to `1`

Comment: Okay, I think I found out the problem. Looks like, even if you set `p_align` the Linux kernel has a minimum alignment of `ELF_MIN_ALIGN`, which is usually the page size

Comment: @tuket I've updated the answer -- `p_align` doesn't have anything to do with it, but (lack of) alignment is indeed the cause.